Curl - getting error - The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline
Can someone help me running curl command line. I am new to curl and I need to run this.
See my command and the error. If I run curl without the single quote around https, I am getting the below error. If I put the single quotes around. I again get little different error.
Curl -u username https://ttt-xapq01.abcinc.local/xxxxxx/api/v1/Erp.BO.Partxxx/Parts?$select=PartNum,TTT_PN_c&$top=2000
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
'$top' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Thanks
Lado
If I run my https through my web browser, I am getting the below Json result back but Curl is giving me an error explained above.
{
"odata.metadata": "https://ttt-xapq01.abcinc.local/xxxxxx/api/v1/Erp.BO.Partxxx/Parts?$select=PartNum,TTT_PN_c&$top=2000",
"value": [
{
"PartNum": " 43115-15-REPAIR",
"TTT_PN_c": ""
},
{
"PartNum": "00274753",
"TTT_PN_c": ""
},
{
"PartNum": "00274795",
"TTT_PN_c": ""
}

This is not about programming or development thus offtopic, but: you are using the Windows port of curl, probably from CMD although you didn't say, and in CMD (for most things) singlequotes don't work like a Unix shell, but doublequotes do. Use curl -u username "url_containing_ampersand". Add --ssl-revoke-best-effort (or -ssl-no-revoke) to bypass the error about checking revocation (in this port).

I need to use Curl for my project. Once I successfully run the Curl from command line, I can then call Curl from my Magic program for API calling.

If I use double quotes and --ssl-no-revoke then I am getting new error:   {"HttpStatus":401,"ReasonPhrase":"REST API Exception","ErrorMessage":"Password has expired for user: username.\r\n\r\nTo restore access, please contact your local administrator.","ErrorType":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException","CorrelationId":"dc6d721f-5abc-4797-b51b-b09c7e8855fb"}

So that means curl is now working. Does the request still work in the browser? I bet it doesn't.

My https request worked through the browser but through Curl not working.
